# Are discussions with US immigration officers audio or video recorded when clearing immigration after entering the US by air?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports

I'm interested in any airport, any circumstance. If recorded, I'd be interested to know for how long the records are kept.

Comment: I don't believe any of these conversations are routinely recorded, not even in secondary, as CBP really like to be able to lie in their reports and don't like evidence that contradicts whatever they want to write. Which is also why they don't want you to record...

Comment: Actually, I believe ALL conversations are recorded, even in secondary, to provide support for any legal proceeding to follow. Whether or not they would make them available upon FOIA request is another question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you have any evidence to back up your assertion that the 'CBP really like to be able to lie'?

Comment: Of course, if the subjacent question is "can I tell a different story each time I meet the nice CBP guys because they won't remember what I said last time", the answer is "don't"...

Comment: @jcaron no worries, I didn't have in mind this subjacent question. On the contrary I hope they do have recordings to protect both the interviewers and the interviewees.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass A wide variety of news stories over the past few years. Mostly they are screwing over migrants, but visitors do occasionally get caught up in this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You're now flagged for secondary interviews and hassle every time you meet the nice CBP people ;->

Comment: @jcaron Oh, I know. It's a real pain in the ass.

Comment: If you go there with this attitude, it doesn't surprise me if you get secondary inspection every time.

Comment: @Aganju what attitude?

Comment: This was in reference to @MichaelHampton 's comments.

Comment: @Aganju What attitude? It's not about me. I'm quite pleasant to the border officials. But I have a long and storied history with the US government, too long to get into here, but it means I'm quite surprised if I _don't_ automatically get secondary when I come back into the US.

Answer (score 5):

The Department of Homeland Security's Customs and Border Patrol uses a system called [CAVSS](https://www.dhs.gov/publication/centralized-area-video-surveillance-system) (Centralized Area Video Surveillance System) and in 2018 was evaluating [IDVRS](https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/national-media-release/cbp-evaluate-incident-driven-video-recording-system) (Incident Driven Video Recording System) which are body-cams for individuals.

The length of time CAVSS recordings are kept are listed in the Privacy Impact Assessment PDF, Section 5.1, available at the first link.

Whether or not they've actually installed surveillance in ALL airports I don't know, and I'm not certain they will make this information public.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up:  [How can I obtain the audio or video recording of discussions with US immigration officers when clearing immigration after entering the US by air?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157293/1810)