# How can I obtain the audio or video recording of discussions with US immigration officers when clearing immigration after entering the US by air?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports

This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157199/1810) mentions that some discussions with US immigration officers when clearing immigration after entering the US by air are recorded. How can one obtain these recordings?

Comment: Your question presumes a fact not in evidence. Because a recording is made, it does not follow that one may obtain a copy of the recording. It's possible or even likely that national security exceptions appear in the FOIA to prevent certain disclosures, and border recordings may well be included. I'm not saying these recordings cannot be obtained, only that it's not yet certain they can.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "You can't" is a valid answer. No presumption. Thanks for the information.

Comment: From my POV, a two-parter (Can they be obtained? How?) would have been logically superior. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [DHS FOIA  (Freedom of Information Act) / Privacy Act Request Submission Form](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-foia-privacy-act-request-submission-form) form from the DHS.